# Хранение переменной в сессии в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, сессия

Можно хранить промежуточные значения в сессии с помощью JavaScript? Какие недостатки у этого способа, если он существует?

Например, мне нужно хранить значение, на основе которого будет задаваться поведение скрипта на странице.

В указанном примере это `currentAtomicNumber`, который сравнивает значением, полученным из атрибута, ниже привожу кусок кода:

```
function openElementDetailBlock(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  var currentAtomicNumber;

  while (target != this) {
    if (target.hasAttribute('data-number')) {
      var atomicNumber = target.getAttribute('data-number');

      if (atomicNumber != currentAtomicNumber) {
        elementDetailBlock.classList.toggle('element-detail_opened');
        setTimeout(elementDetailBlock.classList.add('element-detail_opened'), 1000);
        currentAtomicNumber = atomicNumber;
      }
    }
    target = target.parentNode;
  }
}
```

Одним из решений вижу использование скрытого поля, атрибут, которого изменяется на полученное значение, но это решение кажется мне не слишком правильным.

Подскажите, какие могут быть способы сохранения значения, если JS не подходит для этой задачи?

Comment: что за сессия имеется ввиду?

Comment: @Grundy сессия пользователя, до закрытия браузера.

Comment: _какие могут быть способы сохранения значения_ - сохранения для чего?

Comment: [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: @Grundy сохранения любого значения, для того, чтобы использовать в скрипте. привел пример, где мы считываем атрибут, который должен сравниваться с сохраненным значением. допустим если клик по уникальному элементу, мы показываем его детализацию

Comment: @Grundy у sessionStorage есть недостатки? часто применяется? оформите как ответ, я вам хоть плюс поставлю

Comment: Можно использовать кукисы. Особенно если значение не обьемное.

Comment: @nick_n_a можно, но некоторые пользователи запрещают хранение куков

Comment: @while1pass, с storage Тоже не все гладко

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для хранения данных на время сессия на клиенте можно использовать [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) - это то же самое, что и [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) - но данный очищаются в момент окончания сессии.

---

Альтернативное решение cookies - при отсутствии указания поля expires, время действия cookies - составляет время сессии.

---

Недостатком обоих методов является то, что хранить можно **только** строки, поэтому для работы с объектами их придется сериализовать/десериализовывать.

Кроме того, и cookie могут быть отключены в браузере, и `Storage` - может либо вообще не поддерживаться, на каких-либо устройствах/браузерах либо, например в приватном режиме браузера Safari на iOS будет отсутствовать возможность что-то записать в него.

Comment: пока из двух вариантов меня устраивает Storage. тем более он поддерживается большим количеством браузеров http://caniuse.com/#search=localStorage. за недостатки обоих способов спасибо, надо почитать еще